# Search for Groups in Facebook with FacePy not working

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facepy

I'm trying to search for groups in Facebook using FacePY and cannot get a wildcard search happening either with FQL or with search.

What I want to have happen is the equivalent of what you get with this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=WORDS&type=groups
```

My python code looks like this:

```
graph = GraphAPI(access_token)
data = graph.search(type="group",term="words", page=False, retry=3)
with open('fb-teacher-groups.json', 'w') as outfile:
json.dump(data, outfile, indent = 4,cls=DecimalEncoder)
```

Anybody have any ideas how you'd do a wildcard search of the type SELECT name, gid FROM group WHERE name like "%words%"

I know that you cannot do the above in FQL as name is not an indexed field.

All help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently an open bug because the Graph API search for groups always return an empty data array: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/862756217087760/

A wildcard search via the FQL `group` table is not possible, because the name is not an indexed field as you already wrote.

Comment: I subscribed to the bug and the more developers subscribe on this the soonest we 'll have a fix.