# facebook graph api - search group is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, facebook-group

Earlier i was searching for groups with a particular keyword on facebook using -
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=query&type=group&access_token=abcd..

Since last month it has stopped working. This search now returns always for any
keyword an empty data array. While for types page,user,event,post still returns
proper results. This happened by the time versioning was introduced. I tested
also with the Graph API Explorer with different versions and none worked.
You can check it from here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Tobi you answered my question, but i would like to send
the developers searching for this issue to subscribe here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/862756217087760/
If you edit your answer linking to Facebook Bugs instead
your thread i will mark your answer as correct :) Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tobi mentioned there is a bug for this on Facebook.
If you face the same issue subscribe here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/862756217087760/

The more developers subscribe, the soonest we'll have
a fix i guess.

Answer (score 2):

There's an open bug at FB for this. See my answer here: [Search for Groups in Facebook with FacePy not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196049/search-for-groups-in-facebook-with-facepy-not-working/24199280#24199280) I don't think that there's anything you can do at the moment except wait and hope FB will fix this soon.